# Get the bounds of a WMS layer in Leaflet using JavaScript

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, getcapabilities

Is there a function for calculating the bounds of a line in Leaflet maps. I have many single line layers on a leaflet map. The lines are served from GeoServer WMS. Line layer example:-

```
var HKL = L.tileLayer.wms(localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?, {
    layers: 'HKLine',
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png',
    tiled: true,}).addTo(map);
```

Each line is attached to a menu item in a drop-down menu. On clicking the menu, I want the map to zoom to the associated line. For this, I need the bounds for each line. I can calculate manually like this:

```
var HKLinecorner1 = L.latLng(y1, x1), 
HKLinecorner2 = L.latLng(y2, x2), 
HKLinebounds = L.latLngBounds(HKLinecorner1, HKLinecorner2 );
```

And zoom to the line with `map.fitBounds(HKLinebounds)`. I am looking for a way to calculate the bounds for each dynamically using a leaflet method/function. I have tried different methods and non seems to work. I tried the `getBounds()` on a line, for example
`HKLine.getBounds()` but it gives an error `HKLine.getBounds() is not a function`.

Any ideas of how i can do this.

Comment: There is no explanation in the post, looks like only a suggestion.

Comment: The linked answer contains the words «Leaflet doesn't have anything for parsing this». That means that the answer for your question is "no, there is no Leaflet function for calculating bounds of WMS layers".

Comment: I serve the layer as a non tiled layer, its a personal preference and you can read about it  here https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.nontiledlayer

Comment: Edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: Question is changed now, you are not using plugin any more. Then see comment from @IvanSanchez.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question as asked is to parse the `getCapabilities` response and look at the provided bounding box for each layer.

An easier way to do it might be to not store the features as individual layers but as a single layer and change your access method to WFS using a filter to specify individual lines (features) and then you have the actual geometry, which will give you an extent to zoom to.

Comment: Would look into your solution.